# asp.net 4.0 web service is not working on the server; can anyone proofread the code?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, database

I downloaded the model from the server and it works perfectly on my
desktop with no code or entity framework modifications. Here is the
new error I am getting from the server version of my web service:

System.Data.MappingException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors:

NightRiseModel.msl(143,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is
not valid. The type
'Edm.DateTimeOffset[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=]'
of member 'User_Events_Timestamp' in type
'nightriseModel.user_events' is not compatible with
'MySql.timestamp[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=0]' of
member 'User_Events_Timestamp' in type
'nightriseModel.Store.user_events'.

NightRiseModel.msl(172,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is
not valid. The type
'Edm.DateTimeOffset[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=]'
of member 'User_Create_Date' in type
'nightriseModel.user' is not compatible with
'MySql.timestamp[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=0]' of
member 'User_Create_Date' in type
'nightriseModel.Store.users'.
  at System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.Init(EdmItemCollection
edmCollection, StoreItemCollection storeCollection, IEnumerable`1
xmlReaders, List`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError)

at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.StoreMetadataEntry.LoadStoreCollection(EdmItemCollection
edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader loader)

at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadItemCollection[T](IItemCollectionLoader`1
itemCollectionLoader, T entry)

at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetOrCreateStoreAndMappingItemCollections(String
cacheKey, MetadataArtifactLoader loader, EdmItemCollection
edmItemCollection, Object& entryToken)

at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.LoadStoreItemCollections(MetadataWorkspace
workspace, DbConnection storeConnection, DbProviderFactory factory,
DbConnectionOptions connectionOptions, EdmItemCollection
edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader artifactLoader)

at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean
initializeAllCollections)

at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.InitializeMetadata(DbConnection
newConnection, DbConnection originalConnection, Boolean
closeOriginalConnectionOnFailure)

at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()

at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()

at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)

at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()

at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)

at NightRiseService.Authentication.Login(String UID, String
Password) in [Path Removed]\authentication.asmx.cs:line 29

Comment: Please format the question (especially code)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the MySql provider is not properly installed. Which isn't horribly far-fetched, it has been known to be a bit persnickety. I'll add that my experience with EF startup messages is that they can often eat the actual, proximal, real exceptions. This could be complaining that it couldn't open the MySqlConnection for some other reason like a bad user/pass or a miskeyed server address.

I would try including whatever binaries are necessary within the app rather than depending on ops properly installing it. I would also work up a better instrumented start-up that could identify what is and is not installed. Needs to be slow and methodical, such as starting by doing a simple mysql connect up to wiring up the EF provider.

Comment: How do I do that on the server, it does not have any developer tools installed? Sorry if that sounds ignorant, this is my first deployment with mySQL and entity framework.

Comment: You add a debug page to your app that walks through the steps. Ie, first it tries to open and close a mysql connection and reports success if it works. Second, it tries to new up the EF context, and reports success or failure. Finally, it would perhaps actually select some data and make sure that does not error out.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be an old thread and you found a solution, but for who runs into this again.

I have just had the same problem and the solution was that MySQL connector on my local machine was different than the one on the server. Worked locally but not when I published to the server.

After upgrading server to new MySQL connector everything worked fine.